# How to pass a constant value as a result of condition in python dataframe using "where " function in one line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I pass constant '1' to X after check condition between x1 and x2 ( if x1 == x2 => return 1 )

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': {0: np.nan, 1: 2.0, 2: 4.0, 3: 1, 4: 8.0}, 
                   'x2': {0: 3.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 5.0, 4: np.nan}})

     x1 x2
0   NaN  3
1    2   2
2    4   2
3    1   5
4    8  NaN
```

if I use

```
df['x'] = df['x1'].where((df["x1"]==df["x2"]),0)

    x1  x2  x
0   NaN  3   0
1    2   2   2
2    4   2   0
3    1   5   0
4    8  NaN  0
```

here I would get value of 'x1' where x1 == x2 , but I want to pass integer of 1 instead of 'x1' how can I accomplish this here ?  to get the result below ?

```
     x1 x2  x
0   NaN  3   0
1    2   2   1
2    4   2   0
3    1   5   0
4    8  NaN  0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, like follows;

```
>>> df['x'] = (df["x1"]==df["x2"]).astype(int)
>>> df
   x1  x2  x
0 NaN   3  0
1   2   2  1
2   4   2  0
3   1   5  0
4   8 NaN  0
```

Comment: Beautiful solution. I was just reminded why Python is so awesome. +1.